# Occasional error on nodejs while working with redis list

Tags: node.js, list, redis, ioredis

I have a cron which runs a NodeJS script every 5 minutes, when I check out the error logs some times it had faced a Redis error :

```
Error: Unknown command LLEN
```

I've used list data structure on Redis to store values in array form, this error happens when I'm trying to pop all the data from lists, I do it using a loop like this :

```
try {
        let activities = [];
        let results = [];
        let len = await Redis.call('LLEN', listKey);
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
            activities[i] = await Redis.rpop(listKey);
            results[i] = JSON.parse(activities[i]);
        }
        return results;
    } catch (err) {
        myLogger.log(err);
    }
```

It works perfectly but what is irritating to me is all these redis errors `Error: Unknown command LLEN` which happens occasionally and does not affect application functionality.